# Некорректно работает сложение длинных чисел c/c++

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Программа учебная, надо написать без использования сторонних библиотек, содержащих длинную арифметику. Написать написал, программа работает, но почему-то аварийно завершается после выполнения, причем как-то случайно, никакой зависимости во входных данных не увидел, при которых возникает завершение. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void ConvertFromStringToIntArray(int number1[], int number2[], string str1, string str2)    //берем из файла числа в виде строк и переводим в динамические массивы
{
        char SomeCharForAtoi[2];
        for(int i = str1.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            SomeCharForAtoi[0] = str1[i];
            SomeCharForAtoi[1] = '\0';
            number1[str1.size()-1-i] = atoi(SomeCharForAtoi);   //заполняем элементы массива цифрами числа в обратном порядке
        }
        for(int i = str2.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            SomeCharForAtoi[0] = str2[i];
            SomeCharForAtoi[1] = '\0';
            number2[str2.size()-1-i] = atoi(SomeCharForAtoi);
        }
}
void show_LongNumber(int number[], int length)  //выводим число на экран
{
    for(int i = length-1; i > -1; i--)
        cout << number[i];
    cout << endl;
}
void add_LongNumbers(int number1[], int number2[], int length1, int length2, int &ResultLength)
{
    if(length1 > length2)
    {
        ResultLength = length1 + 1;                     //длина числа после сложения(максимальная)
        for(int i = length1; i < ResultLength; i++) //заполняю нулями разницу в разрядах
            number1[i] = 0;
        for(int i = length2; i < ResultLength; i++)
            number2[i] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ResultLength = length2 + 1;
        for(int i = length1; i < ResultLength; i++)
            number1[i] = 0;
        for(int i = length2; i < ResultLength; i++)
            number2[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ResultLength-1; i++)              //сам алгоритм сложения
    {
        number1[i] += number2[i];
        number1[i + 1] += (number1[i] / 10);
        number1[i] %= 10;
    }

    if(number1[ResultLength-1] == 0)                      //если первая цифра - ноль, смещаем число
    {
        ResultLength--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    fin.open("input.txt");
    fout.open("output.txt");

    string number1;
    string number2;
    fin >> number1;
    fin >> number2;

    int ResultLength;
    int *FirstNumber = new int[number1.size()];
    int *SecondNumber = new int[number2.size()];
    int length1 = number1.size();
    int length2 = number2.size();
    ConvertFromStringToIntArray(FirstNumber, SecondNumber, number1, number2);
    add_LongNumbers(FirstNumber, SecondNumber, length1, length2, ResultLength);
    show_LongNumber(FirstNumber, ResultLength);
    delete [] FirstNumber;
    delete [] SecondNumber;
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите...
Вы создаете массив `FirstNumber` с `length1` элементами. Передаете его в `ConvertFromStringToIntArray`.

Допустим, `length > length2`. Тогда вы делаете

```
ResultLength = length1 + 1;                 //длина числа после сложения(максимальная)
for(int i = length1; i < ResultLength; i++) //заполняю нулями разницу в разрядах
    number1[i] = 0;
```

Т.е. вы ухитряетесь обращаться к элементу `number1[length1]`, которого, вообще-то, нет... :(

Вроде бы так.

Comment: Да, этого элемента еще нет, но ведь массив - динамический. Разве я не могу произвольно продолжить индексацию? Я специально заполняю на один разряд больше нулем, чтобы потом во время выполнения алгоритма вот здесь: number1[i + 1] += (number1[i] / 10); у меня не было "мусора" в ячейке, когда я буду складывать самое последнее число. Или я не прав?

Comment: Конечно, нет. Вы имеете право работать только с теми элементами, что запросили. Запросили L элементов - все, за пределы индексов от 0 до L-1 - ни туп ногой!...

Comment: Прошу прощения, уже осознал свою глупость на парочке примеров ;) Видимо, потому и завершается случайно, что обращаюсь я к совершенно рандомным ячейкам в памяти. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, если все понятно и ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос птицей принятого ответа :)